# Keep custom folding regions collapsed when formatting in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

When I run "Format code" and/or "Fix ESLint problems" (it's one of those, they're both part of my "on save" config), all my custom folding regions get unfolded. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Looks like a bug, please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the steps to reproduce.